# How do I preserve leading zeroes in Mac Excel?

Tags: ms-office, numbers, csv

I'm using Excel (v 14.4.4) on my Mac (10.9.5).  I have opened a CSV file and I wish to save it to an .xls format (Excel 97-2004 Workbook).  I have a column that has 6 digit numbers, some of which begin with a leading zero.  When I save my CSV to XLS, the cells with leading zeroes lose these leading zeroes.  How do I keep them there?

Answer (score 1):

From the Home tab, select the cells you wish to format, and from the format drop-down under Number select Custom. Or, right-click and choose Format Cells, or hit Cmd-1.

This will pop-up a dialog window with the various formatting options.

Again, make sure you're on Custom.

In the Type box type in: 000000

Click Ok.

Alternatively - change the formatting type to text. This will keep whatever you type in the box.

Comment: Although this displays the value as "062601", when I click on the cell, the value still appears as "62601" in that little window above the columns.  I don't want the value to just appear as "062601," I want it to actually be "062601".  Something is getting lost when I import from CSV.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you are trying do do with the spreadsheet but putting <'> (**single quote**) in-front of the leading zero will preserve it with the conversion from CSV to xls format.

As @Alex says converting the cells to text will work, and inserting the single quote at the start of the cell just converts it to text.